# Should I sent another follow-up email to editor if there is no response after submitting the revision?

Tags: mathematics, peer-review, editors, communication

I am a Ph.D. student in pure mathematics. Recently, I received a very positive review of one of my articles from a good (or at least average) journal. After a minor revision, I sent back the revised paper to the editor. After getting no confirmation after 6 days, I sent him another follow-up email saying "Please confirm upon receipt of the revised paper". But still, four days passed, and I got no reply. So I am confused about whether he really received the revised paper or not.

Let me tell you that the journal only follows email communications; there is no online submission portal. We (me and the editor) have used the same email message from submission to status inquiry to revision; that is, I submitted the paper and he received it by replying to my message, then I queried the status of the paper by replying to the same email message, and he answered the status, and so on. So far, we've communicated about 15–20 times over the same email follow-up. Is there any limit to replies in Gmail? Or, simply, he is very busy, so he received it but forgot to reply both times? It has been 10 days since I sent the revised paper, and 4 days ago I sent a follow-up message to know if he received it.

Would it be annoying to inquire in a separate message (of the same email address) if he received the revised paper?  Or, should I wait for the final decision, assuming that he has received my revised paper?

I appreciate your guidance

Comment: Normally the email telling you that minor revisions are requested should tell you how to submit the revision. Did you follow the description there? If it links to an editorial system, that may automatically confirm receipt. Both as author and editor I'm not used to this amount of direct communication (15-20 times is A LOT; very often there is no such communication whatsoever; submission is through a system and then the author lets reviewers and editor just do their job). I can understand that you want a confirmation of receipt, but as editor I'd really want you to follow the standard route.

Comment: @ChristianHennig, yes I followed every step. The respective journal follows only email communication, there is no online submission-portal. The editor told me to submit back the revised paper, he will be waiting. 15-20 times because the paper was under review for  1 and half years, I enquired review status 4 times in that time span giving a total of 4*2=8 communication, as well as during submission we had 4 (=2*2) communications, finally after the review report we have had 4 (=2*2) communications. So a total of 16 communications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He could be on a conference or other travelling/holidays, maybe even ill. I'd probably give him a some time more (at least a week more) before trying to contact him again using an alternative path. In my experience/view, requesting review status several times is pretty useless (once can be good though), but requesting a confirmation of receipt is rather elementary, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes I will wait some time more, at least this June. After I might email him in July. I enquired review status because it took 16 months and I am a Ph.D. student, so need to finish in time. By separate message, I meant to email him at the same email ID but in a new message.